# Why this code is in endless loop of Retrying to fetch data from the exchange website

Tags: python, spyder

Till the time I dont setup a timer it fetches the data in excel & the dataFrame in Variable explorer, however after setting up a timer of 1 min to fetch the data, excel is completely blank and so is Variable explorer, sometimes it fetches the data every 1 min and sometimes it will just get stuck in endless loop of "Retrying" and I dont get it as to why Variable Explorer is gets completely blank, Using Spyder IDE

What is wrong with it.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import time
from datetime import datetime
import winsound

file = xw.Book("NiftyOptionChainFeed.xlsm")
sh1 = file.sheets("Sheet1")

def oc(sym):

    url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol="+sym
    
    headers = {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "referer": "https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",}
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text
    
    data = json.loads(response)
        
    expiry_list = data['records']['expiryDates']
    
    ce = {}
    pe = {}
    n = 0
    m = 0
    
    for i in data['records']['data']:
        #if i['expiryDate'] == expiry_date:
        try:
            ce[n] = i['CE']
            n = n + 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            pe[m] = i['PE']
            m = m + 1
        except:
            pass
    
    ce_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ce).transpose()
    ce_df.columns = "CE_" + ce_df.columns
    pe_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pe).transpose()
    pe_df.columns = "PE_" + pe_df.columns
        
    df = pd.concat([ce_df, pe_df],axis = 1)
    
    return expiry_list, df

try:
    data = oc(sym)
    sh1.range("A1").value = data[1]
    sh1.range("AO2").options(transpose = True).value = data[0]
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    sh1.range("AQ2").value = timestamp
    time.sleep(90)
except:
    print("retrying")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Up until here (below code) everything works fine. Variable explorer shows the data in the dataframe, data is fetched into excel sheet, but as I progress and try to run it every 1 min, it just gets weird (problem described above)

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import time
from datetime import datetime
import winsound

def oc(sym):

    url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol="+sym
    
    headers = {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "referer": "https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",}
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text
    
    data = json.loads(response)
        
    expiry_list = data['records']['expiryDates']
    
    ce = {}
    pe = {}
    n = 0
    m = 0
    
    for i in data['records']['data']:
        #if i['expiryDate'] == expiry_date:
        try:
            ce[n] = i['CE']
            n = n + 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            pe[m] = i['PE']
            m = m + 1
        except:
            pass
    
    ce_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ce).transpose()
    ce_df.columns = "CE_" + ce_df.columns
    pe_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pe).transpose()
    pe_df.columns = "PE_" + pe_df.columns
        
    df = pd.concat([ce_df, pe_df],axis = 1)
    
    file = xw.Book("NiftyOptionChainFeed.xlsm")
    sh1 = file.sheets("Sheet1")
    sh1.range("A1").value = df
    sh1.range("AO2").options(transpose = True).value = expiry_list
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by add a timer, could you provide a minimal working example and a minimal failing example to better illustrate the problem?

Comment: _get stuck in endless loop of "Retrying"_ What do you mean by "endless loop"?  The only place in the code that I see the message "retrying" is the except block at the very end, and that part isn't in a loop...

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from the website every 1 min and refresh it in the excel and if the data is not fetched I want it to try again in the next 5 secs.

Comment: In your first code fragment the *oc()* function is only ever called once. If there are no exceptions then your program will sleep for 90s then terminate. In your second code fragment the *oc()* function is never invoked

Comment: Spyder's variable explorer doesn't update while code is running, only when it either exits or pauses in the debugger.